# Rails Ancestry: How do I get descendants that are at depth of n of a subtree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ancestry

I have a node which descendants I am interested in. But I am interested in descendants that are found at a specific depth. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? You can just loop down the tree until you reach your desired depth, and collect all the nodes. Consider looking up how to traverse a tree: depth-first vs breadth-first.

Comment: @MrDanA I am aware of tree traversal techniques. What I am looking for is a possible functionality inside the gem that gets this done.

Comment: Does Rails Ancestry allow you to start at a root node and ask for children? If so then you should be able to do a normal tree traversal, and keep a running count of what depth you are at, then gather up the nodes when you're at your desired depth.

Comment: @MrDanA this would be insanely inefficient in my opinion. I want something that does some `LIKE` query on the ancestry field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#selecting-nodes-by-depth

````
Use the at_depth(n)

n being the depth of the nodes that you want to return

Note: the depth begins with value 0```
````